# 48Khz Stereo big endian PCM to 16Khz Mono big endian PCM audio in Rust

Tags: audio, rust

I've been working on this for a while, but never managed to figure out how to get it to work. I have a Vec of 48Khz 16-bit Stereo Big Endian signed PCM audio, and I need this to be 16Khz 16-bit Mono Little endian signed PCM audio.

I've tried working with the libsamplerate and fon crates, but I was unable to figure it out for both of them.

Currently I am able to convert BE to LE, which I do first. I then want to take the Vec and put it in an Audio from the fon crate:

```rs
    //Input data is BE
    let mut input = crate::jni_util::jarray_to_vec::<i16>(env, jshort_array).expect("Something went wrong converting the input data!");

    //First change the endianness from BE to LE
    LittleEndian::from_slice_i16(&mut input.as_mut_slice());
    
    //Get an Audio<Stereo16> object from the input data at 48Khz Stereo
    let input_buf = Audio::<Stereo16>::with_i16_buffer(48_000, input.as_slice());
```

It's failing at this last line with  `panicked at 'assertion failed: '(left == right)'`, which doesn't make any sense to me. Why would the left channel be equal to the right channel, in a stereo signal?

Any help is much appreciated, I've been stuck at this problem for way too long now :"D

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be due to the input slice having an uneven number of items than what the with_i16_buffer() function is expecting.  If I pass a vector to `Audio::<Stereo16>::with_i16_buffer()` with an even number of items, it works, but with an odd number of items, I get the same panic that you get.  If I print the backtrace, it's caused by an assertion in with_i16_buffer:163 `assert_eq!(0, bytes % size_of::<F>())` where F is the frame size (in this case Stereo16, which expects two i16 numbers per frame).  I guess that sort of implies that the data you have is already mono?  It's hard to tell without more context here.  Can you provide some more info on the input data?

Since you want the output to be Mono anyways, you probably want to use `Audio::<Mono16>::with_i16_buffer()`, but if the input data is in stereo, you'd need to remove every other item from the array before passing it to with_i16_buffer() (or average every two i16 numbers together, or however you'd like to convert the data).

Comment: Hm I would have never guessed that could be the issue myself. The input audio is from Discord, which is supposed to be 48Khz 16 bit stereo interleaved BE signed pcm audio.

Ill give the Mono one a go, see what happens then, and otherwhise it is probably fine to just remove an element from the end of the array, since 1 element does not make a lot of difference for speech. Not the cleanest solution but